# Where to find Node Private IP on a Ubuntu Bare Metal?

Tags: rancher

For my "production" homelab, I prepared 5x Bare Metal Server and installed Rancher on top of a Kubernates, also I created a new RKE2 Cluster.

Now I want add an etcd, Control Plane and two worker Nodes.

In Cluster Registry Tab is a checkbox "Show Advanced", expanded I can enter

- node name
- node public ip
- node private ip

Node Name and Public Ip is clear to me. But what is a private ip and how I can find it?

I Use Ubuntu 20 on Bare Metal.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private IP should be in section 2: after "brd"

```
ip -o addr show
```